# Kendo scheduler navigation datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler, kendo-datepicker

I need to get the navigation datepicker in the kendo scheduler (see the picture)[image].

in my app i need to add restrection to the date picker for example minimum  date is today or maximum date is 10 day from now.

Is there a way to get that datePicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use min and max options of scheduler to limit it:

```
$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
  date: new Date(),
  min: new Date(),
  max: new Date('2016/09/17'),
  .....................
```

http://dojo.telerik.com/ehIYi